# MSDN is down.... is there a way to search a cache of its content?

Tags: msdn

I can't access msdn.com and a quick search of #msdn on twitter shows that other people are seeing the outage.  Is there any way to search a cache of MSDN content?

Comment: I can't believe that this is getting answers and upvotes. While this maybe true and effects lots of people this hardly qualifies as a programming QA. However, you can try the [way back machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, one of my colleagues found the answer... do a Google search, click the faint right arrows to the right of the hit you want to get the Preview, then click on the Cached link.

**EDIT:** If you want to be able to follow the links in the cached page, install one of these: http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=google+cache&submit=Search

Answer (score 2):

Sure, do the search on Google (`site:msdn.microsoft.com foo`) and use their cache.

Comment: I can do the search and see hits, but I can't access the content (even cached content)

Comment: You may be having other issues in that case; [Google's cache](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQIDAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebcache.googleusercontent.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dcache%3ATvVureG5lacJ%3Amsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fwc7014hz(v%253Dvs.71).aspx%2B%26cd%3D1%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk%26gl%3Dus&ei=f0W-T5qnIfTbiAKN3ui3Cw&usg=AFQjCNF2u0Cog76cX1aps7Y_DHXvhF1qeg&sig2=sAc-e6LNRSs_1wS22WY8tg) works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah, it's working for me too now that I know how to get to it (see my answer)