# SPSite Class - MSDN documentation

Tags: c#, sharepoint, msdn

I realise this is a silly question but the MSDN can't be accessed from my network `"Server Error: 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server."` and I can't just sit here and twiddle my thumbs.

I know of no alternative to the MSDN, and my local Visual Studio help thing doesn't have anything on this class.

Please could someone copy and paste the entries for `Microsoft.Sharepoint` `SPSite` class, specifically the Constructor but the whole article would be useful.
I am getting a FileNotFoundException and need to know how the URL property is supposed to be formatted.

In case any of you just happen to know.

```
    public Dictionary<string, SPFolder> GetFolderCollection(string siteURL, string docLibraryName)
    {
        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(siteURL + ":23179"))
        {
            SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb();
            SPList oList = oWeb.Lists[docLibraryName];

            SPFolderCollection oFolders = oList.RootFolder.SubFolders;

            foreach (SPFolder folder in oFolders)
            {
                foundFolders.Add(folder.Name, folder);
            }
            return foundFolders;
        }
    }
```

Edit: Cheers, google cache ftw.

For the record I was pointing to the IIS site root, not the Sharepoint "Site". Was confusing the Sharepoint terminology.

Comment: Rather than put it on StackOverflow, why don't you just look at a [Google Cached version of the page?](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Kbp3ROKhyrgJ:msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.aspx+Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPSite&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari) This "question" is very localized.

Comment: Good shout, put that as an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739361/msdn-is-down-is-there-a-way-to-search-a-cache-of-its-content

Comment: MSDN was down for everyone earlier today.

Comment: You will want to put create the SPWeb oWeb object in a using statement too like you did for the SPSite oSite object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Represents a collection of sites in a Web application, including a
>   top-level Web site and all its subsites. Each SPSite object, or site
>   collection, is represented within an SPSiteCollection object that
>   consists of the collection of all site collections in the Web
>   application.
>
> Inheritance Hierarchy
>
> System.Object
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite
>
> Namespace:  Microsoft.SharePoint
>
> Assembly:  Microsoft.SharePoint (in
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.dll)
>
> Available in Sandboxed Solutions: Yes
>
> Available in SharePoint Online
>
> [SubsetCallableTypeAttribute] [ClientCallableTypeAttribute(Name =
>   "Site", ServerTypeId = "{E1BB82E8-0D1E-4e52-B90C-684802AB4EF6}")]
>   public class SPSite : IDisposable
>
> Remarks
>
> To instantiate an SPSite object for a specific site collection on an
>   ASP.NET page, or for a specific site collection within a console
>   application, use the SPSite constructor as follows: C# VB
>
> SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("Absolute_URL");
>
> Within an ASP.NET application, you can use the Site property of the
>   SPContext class to return an SPSite object that represents the current
>   site collection, as follows: C#
>
> SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
>
> Use the Sites property of the SPWebApplication class to return an
>   SPSiteCollection object that represents the collection of site
>   collections in a SharePoint Web application. Use an indexer to return
>   a single site collection from the collection. For example, if the
>   collection of site collections is assigned to a variable named
>   oSiteCollections, use oSiteCollections[index] in C#, or
>   oSiteCollections(index) in Visual Basic, where index is either the
>   display name or the index number of the site collection in the
>   collection.
>
> Certain objects implement the IDisposable interface, and you must
>   avoid retaining these objects in memory after they are no longer
>   needed. If you create your own SPSite object, you can use the Dispose
>   method to close the object. You can also instead implement a using
>   statement so that the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR)
>   automatically releases the memory that is used to store the site
>   collection as follows: C# VB
>
> using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("Absolute_URL") {
>       ... }
>
> However, if you have a reference to a shared resource, such as when
>   the object is provided by the GetContextSite method in a Web Part, do
>   not use either method to close the object. Using either method on a
>   shared resource causes an Access Violation error to occur. In
>   scenarios where you have a reference to a shared resource, instead let
>   Microsoft SharePoint Foundation or your portal application manage the
>   object.
>
> For more information about good coding practices, see Disposing
>   Objects.
>
> Important
>
> If you install Infrastructure Update for Windows SharePoint Services
>   3.0 (KB951695), custom solutions may fail if they call the SharePoint object model while impersonation is suspended. If you use Windows
>   authentication and your code calls the SharePoint object model from an
>   Internet Information Services (IIS) worker process, the request must
>   impersonate the calling user’s identity. SharePoint Foundation
>   configures ASP.NET to impersonate the calling user automatically, but
>   your code may work unexpectedly, or fail, if you suspend
>   impersonation--for example, by calling the RevertToSelf function of
>   the Windows API, or by calling the
>   System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate method and
>   passing IntPtr.Zero as the value of the user token parameter. Even if
>   your code does not explicitly revert to self, it might be called by
>   ASP.NET after it reverts to self, such as happens when implementing a
>   virtual path provider; if your code does not impersonate the calling
>   user, it might not function properly.
>
> Thread Safety
>
> Any public static
>   (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any
>   instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Constructors:

```
    Name    Description
Public method   SPSite(Guid)    Initializes a new instance of the SPSite class based on the specified ID for a site collection.
Public method   SPSite(String)  Initializes a new instance of the SPSite class based on the specified URL.
Public method   SPSite(Guid, SPUrlZone)     Initializes a new instance of the SPSite class based on the specified site collection GUID and URL zone.
Public method   SPSite(Guid, SPUserToken)   Initializes a new instance of the SPSite class based on the specified site collection GUID and user token.
Public method   SPSite(String, SPUserToken)     Initializes a new instance of the SPSite class based on the specified absolute URL and user token.
Public method   SPSite(Guid, SPUrlZone, SPUserToken)    Initializes a new instance of the SPSite class based on the specified site collection GUID, URL zone, and user token.
```